# The definition of the connection on the principle bundle

Tags: fiber-bundles, principal-bundles

Nakahara defines the connection one-form on the principle bundle as follows:

[image]

I'm a little confused about the motivation for $g^{-1}$ in the latter equation.

Roughly speaking, we can think of $R_{g*}X$ as of $Xg$ (true only for matrix groups, of course). Now, assume $A\in g$. Then:

\begin{gather}
\omega(A) \cong A
\end{gather}
(since we have an isomorphism between the Lie algebra and the vertical tangent subspace).

But
\begin{gather}
\omega(R_{g*}A) = g^{-1} \omega(A) g = g^{-1} A g \ncong  R_{g*}A = Ag
\end{gather}

What am I missing? So far, it seems like the consistent definition would be just $R^*_g\omega=\omega g$.

**UPDATE**

One of my colleagues has suggested the following. Applying $\omega$ to a vector involves smth pulling it back to the tangent space of unit element, which produces $g^{-1}$ on the left.